# Set the default value for a password field on a custom form

Tags: users

I have created a custom user register form. I want to set the default value for the password, and confirm the password fields.
My point is that, whenever form error occurs, the password fields get cleared. Users don't need to type the password again and again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [password](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#password) as form element type for the password, it does not support the *#default_value* property. The password field  is cleared when there is a validation error.